# OSM update without losing own additional data

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, database, update, osmosis

I have added data (e.g. name keys) to my OSM PostgreSql database. How can I update my database without deleting or overwriting this data? In other words, how can I merge newer OSM data to my existing database without losing my additional data?

Comment: I guess this depends on quite *how* you added your additional data.  If you created extra columns or (worse) added more values to the tags column, then it's going to be difficult.  Easier if your own data is in separate tables, keyed to the OSM id.

Comment: I want to use iD editor and the rails port. If I use Osmosis to update my database, are my additional tags (e.g. name_abcd, with key value) deleted or preserved?

Answer (score 2):

In the OpenStreetMap environment so-called "diff-files" are used to update your PostgreSQL/PostGIS OSM-DB. This can be done based on minutely, hourly or daily diffs. There are several tools to do this, I recommend to use [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Latest_stable_version). [This OSM wiki page gives a comprehensive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm/diffs) overview.

In the German OSM forum there is [quite a good thread](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=14997) on this topic.
As already mentioned by @Toby Speight in the comments you should keep your updates seperated from the original OSM data so they wont be messed up.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! If I keep my additional data (tags) separated to another table, then I cannot use iD editor to edit this tags. So, it depends how osmosis import the changes. Are my additional tags (e.g. name_abcd, with key value) deleted or preserved?

Comment: Diff-files only contain the *differences* between two OSM database timestamps. Therefore you should keep your additional tags in the seperated column. After importing the diff-file create a new column based on the osm-tag-column and enrich it with your additional tags. This will keep the OSM dataset clean (and you have a back-up of your additional data).